# how can get call stack from Dump file for a web IIS MVC application by visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dump, pdb-files

My mvc web site on IIS 8.5 after 5 minutes does not response any more and i have not any idea what is my problem,
I'm trying to detect its call stack by dump file in visual studio 2013 or 2015.
I made a dump file in window task manager and opened it in visual studio and set its symboles path (my bin folder contains pdb and dll filse) and start debuge managed code but i could not achieve to call stack ...

[image]

Comment: open the dmp in windbg (part of the Windows SDK- Debugging Tools) and run here **!analyze -v -hang**

Comment: Thanks for your time ,can i do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: I have no idea. I never used VS to debug dmp files.